# Hibernate Authentication Error with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am having a difficult time trying to set a connection with hibernate to a SQL Server. I should create a connection to the following data source DataSource=server,port. It seem strange that the port must be specify with a comma instead of :

When I connect to it through Visual Studio 2012 this is how it looks:

Data Source=server,17001;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=username

In order to connect it I create the following hibernate configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://server.fqdn</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.port">port</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.databasename">database</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1000</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But I get the following Exception when the connection is attempted:

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'username'. ClientConnectionId:c619c1dc-2c6c-4c6e-bc81-7d3619ee9ff1

I know for sure that the user and password are correct as I am using them to connect to the database through Visual Studio 2012 and they works fine.
Any idea of how should I face it?

Comment: I believe that configuration uses database logins. Perhaps your database is using domain logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mark this as resolved. The issue was that I was specifying the port as a separate property:

`<property name="hibernate.connection.port">port</property>.`

When I add it to the connection string parameter

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://server.fqdn:port</property>
```

it works